# Вывести определенную страницу?

Tags: wordpress

Как вывести определенную страницу в `wordpress`? То есть нужно вывести контент страницы по ее id. Все обыскал. Есть варианты вывода дочерних по `id` но как саму ее вытащить - не пойму что то.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать функцию `get_post` (для записей).

Пример:

```
<?php
  $id = 7;// Обязательно передавать переменную
  $post = get_post($id); 
  $content = $post->post_content;
?>
```

[get_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Справочник_по_функциям/get_post)

**UPD #1**

Для страниц функция похожая:

[get_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page)